# Need help calculating grace period

Tags: usa, visa, immigration

I think I have accrued 1 day overstay on an F1 visa in the USA, beyond the 60-day grace period. Different online tools give different results. My 60-day grace period began on October 24th, 2017 (date on document) and I left on December 23rd 2017. I thought it was 60 days. I'm confused.

How does USCIS calculate the grace period?

Comment: Do you mean you graduated on Oct 24 (or Oct 23)? Or your I-20 ended on on Oct 24 (or Oct 23)?

Comment: @user102008 as noted in the comments to the related [question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/115773/19400) on [Travel.SE], October 24th is the date on which Gator received an H-1B rejection notice.  However, in this question it is said to be the date on the document.  I suggested that by inductive reasoning, if a 1-day grace period would mean having to leave on the 25th, then a 60-day period would mean having to leave on the 23rd, but I don't know if this is actually how USCIS calculates it, so I suggested asking here.

Comment: @ user102008 I got H1b denial notice on October 24th and I was told by my lawyer and school DSO that I have 60 days to sort out my things ( car,furniture etc). Like phoog said, I don't know how actually USCIS calculates grace period, phoog's way make sense. Any inputs will be helpful